# How to grab page content by class in Chrome extension?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I want to grab content from page by class. I wrote chrome extension, but I don't get the contents of the element. I recieved [object Object] in textarea. I tried to get the page title when I wrote chrome.runtime.sendMessage(document.title); in payload.js and it's work, but not work when I try to get content by class. Please tell me how to fix my solution?

**manifest.json**

```
{
  "manifest_version": 2,

  "name": "Scrap",
  "description": "Scrap",
  "version": "1.0",
  "author": "",

  "background": {
    "scripts": ["popup.js"],
    "persistent": true
  },

  "permissions": [
    "tabs",
    "http://*/",
    "https://*/"
  ],
  "browser_action": {
    "default_icon": "logo.png",
    "default_popup": "popup.html"
  }
}
```

**popup.js**

```
  window.addEventListener('load', function (evt) {
        chrome.extension.getBackgroundPage().chrome.tabs.executeScript(null, {
            file: 'payload.js'
        });;
    });


    chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function (message) {
        document.getElementById('json-content').innerHTML = message;
    });
```

**popup.html**

```
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
    <title>Scrap</title>
    <script src="popup.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-GJzZqFGwb1QTTN6wy59ffF1BuGJpLSa9DkKMp0DgiMDm4iYMj70gZWKYbI706tWS" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <style>
        .container {
            min-width: 500px;
            padding: 1rem 1.5rem;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="container">
        <form>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="exampleFormControlTextarea1">JSON</label>
                <textarea class="form-control" id="json-content" rows="3"></textarea>
            </div>

        </form>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

**payload.js**

```
chrome.runtime.sendMessage(document.getElementsByClassName("something"));
```

**page for grab**

```
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Scrap</title>
    <script src="popup.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-GJzZqFGwb1QTTN6wy59ffF1BuGJpLSa9DkKMp0DgiMDm4iYMj70gZWKYbI706tWS" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <style>
        .container {
            min-width: 500px;
            padding: 1rem 1.5rem;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <h1>Test</h1>
<p class="something">Text</p>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Messaging can transfer only simple types, not DOM elements. Extract the text first and send it as an array of strings or a single string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your payload.js you are not getting the text of the class but the elements with that class, so it shows that it is an object. Also, getElementsByClassName returns multiple results that you need to go threw.

I would do something like this in my payload.js file:

```
var result = "";
var somethings = document.getElementsByClassName("something");
for (var i = 0; i < somethings.length; i++) {
   result += somethings[i].textContent;
}
chrome.runtime.sendMessage(result);
```

Note that this will return all the text inside the elements that have that class.

EDIT: If you want to get the first element of the page with that class you can use querySelector instead.

```
var something = document.querySelector(".something");
chrome.runtime.sendMessage(something.textContent);
```